# Extract Letters of the first and the third position in R

Tags: r

I have

```
x <- c("AAA,", "BBB,", "GTWE,", "EYREW,", "RYE")
```

I want to get

```
y <- c("AA,", "BB,", "GW,", "ER,", "RE")
```

how should I do in R ? Thank you.

Comment: `paste(substring(var,1,1), substring(var,3,3), sep="")`

Comment: Or `sub("^(.).(.).*$", "\\1\\2", x)`.